# Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

In our applications, we are saving the User email id and user name in shared preference and sending those to Firebase analytics. In this case what should be the answer of the below question that Google is asking :

> Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types?
>
> - Yes
> - No

Please suggest a suitable option.

Comment: Post this question in [Android StackExchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: posted here : https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247826/your-app-is-not-compliant-with-google-play-policies

Comment: @CristianTraìna please don't suggest [Android.SE] for questions related to app development and publishing. It's off-topic on there.

Comment: @AndrewT. yes sorry, my bad, I've been deceived by the URL